# How to parse this json with jquery?

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to create my first node.js program with socket.io and I want to store the chat history and then when a user joins have the chat history pushed to his browser. I have the chat saving and pushing and the json that is sent looks like this:

```
[
    [
        {
            "username": "Warren2",
            "text": "Test"
        },
        {
            "username": "Warren2",
            "text": "Test2"
        },
        {
            "username": "Warren2",
            "text": "Test3"
        }
    ]
]
```

On my html page I have a javascript that has this

```
socket.on('updatehistory', function(data) {

}
```

The code that I put in there will be executed when the updatehistory message is pushed. I'm a n00b and pretty lost lol. This is what I tried:

```
socket.on('updatehistory', function (data) {
   $.each(json.results, function(username,text){
      $('#conversation').append('<b>'+ username + ':</b> ' + text + '<br>');
  });
});
```

This is the exact debug message for the updatehistory event from node.js

```
debug - websocket writing 5:::{"name":"updatehistory","args":[[{"username":"W
arren2","text":"Test"},{"username":"Warren2","text":"Test2"},{"username":"Warren
2","text":"Test3"}]]}
```

Can someone help me figure out how to parse that (preferable with jquery).
Thank you :D

Comment: you can use Jquery plugin, for example smth like this: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/

Comment: or look there, there is a collection of such plugins :)
http://www.jquery4u.com/json/15-jquery-json-plugins/

Comment: Do you get the data as in after all the functions are done?

Comment: You don't like [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)?

Answer (score 0):

I love this solution:
http://www.rahulsingla.com/blog/2010/05/jquery-encode-decode-arbitrary-objects-to-and-from-json/

Comment: I get "JSON.parse: unexpected character" I think there is an extra set of brackets surrounding everything which is causing my problems. Not sure how to deal with that.

Comment: try prase your JSON with a different tool (php/perl/anything that is near for fast test). Maybe JSON is not valid? i've used this library in many websites.. never got such errors..

Answer (score 0):

I would give you a way to traverse your data if you want to do it all by yourself and its just a 5 line code.Here goes the first one.I have alerted the username and password to show you that it actually works in the sample.

http://jsfiddle.net/shivkumarganesh/gfff5/

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        var k=[
    [
        {
            "username": "Warren1",
            "text": "Test"
        },
        {
            "username": "Warren2",
            "text": "Test2"
        },
        {
            "username": "Warren3",
            "text": "Test3"
        }
    ]
];

for(i in k)
    {
    var l=k[i];
     for (j in l)
    {
        alert("Username:"+l[j].username+" --  Message:"+l[j].text);
    }
    }​
    });
```

neither `JSON.parse()` nor `$.parseJson` were working.So i consider this the best solution.

Comment: How would I remove the extra set of brackets? The json is what I get from node.js

Comment: When I log the input from node.js to the console I get
[Object { username="Warren2", text="test1"}, Object { username="Warren2", text="test2"}, Object { username="Warren2", text="test3"}]

Comment: @0xDECAFBAD I have solved your problem, now no need to edit the code anyways. You can directly feed in the same string. I have updated the code in fiddle as well as my answer above. This is the fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/shivkumarganesh/gfff5/